# INSTEAD OF UPDATE triggers doing the standard update it was replacing

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

This seems like a really stupid question but I can't find any information on the net how to do this.

If you're designing a trigger that will wrap an Update operation, how do you actually conduct that operation? Do I have to explicitly mention every column in `tbl_MyTable` to perform the update? That seems far to maintenance intensive for future potential schema changes, and I don't want to unnecessarily hit `Insert` or `Delete` triggers while recursion is enabled.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_MyUpdateTrigger]
ON [dbo].[tbl_MyTable]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
--Do the standard update operation on tbl_MyTable that this trigger is replacing
END
```

In short, how can you fulfil an update without resorting to deleting from deleted and inserting from inserted, or explicitly mentioning every column in your table. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using an INSTEAD OF [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx) you have to do the UPDATE - no getting around it. If you were to use an AFTER trigger then you wouldn't need to do the UPDATE at all. Which type of trigger you should be using depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Just to clarify one thing though, you don't delete from the 'deleted' pseudo table and insert into the 'inserted' pseudo table. You do the UPDATE on the real table, joined to the 'inserted' pseudo table on an appropriate key to get the new values.

If I had to do this I might be tempted to use something like this to save me typing too much :)

```
select N't.' + quotename(name) + N' = i.' + quotename(name) + N', ' as [--SQL] 
from sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('dbo.MyTable') 
order by column_id
```

Don't forget to remove the PK columns and any other inappropriate columns (i.e. timestamps) from the generated list.

Comment: If someone updates the primary key, inserted will have nothing to join to, hence why I was thinking you had to delete from your real table based on the deleted psudo, and insert based on the inserted. But I don't especially want to do that because of recursion.

Comment: Good point! However, I see this more as a design issue - there are lots of other issues around allowing primary keys to be updated. You could use the  [UPDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187326.aspx) function to test whether the primary key columns have been updated and reject the update.

Comment: Ah right, so I could treat updates to the PK as deletes+inserts, it does make sense. For everything that doesn't involve a PK update, just update based on inserted... does that still involved explicit mentioning of every column in tbl_MyTable?

Comment: @Izzy - yup, every column, although if I had to do this I might be tempted to use something like `select N't.' + quotename(name) + N' = i.' + quotename(name) + N', ' as [--SQL] from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('dbo.MyTable') order by column_id` to save me typing too much :)

Comment: Curses! If you edit that hint into your answer I'll accept. :)